# SQL query failure for SET

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to run what I thought was a simple query in PHPmyadmin. I keep getting a syntax failure for my set value... any ideas?

```
UPDATE
    `wp_postmeta`
SET
    `meta_value` = 'a:1:{i:0;a:5:{s:5:"index";s:1:"0";s:4:"name";s:8:"Donation";s:6:"amount";s:5:"10.00";s:5:"limit";s:0:"";s:6:"bought";s:0:"";}}'
WHERE
    `meta_key` = 'edd_variable_prices' AND `meta_value` != '';
```

ERROR Msg:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near ''a:1:{i:0)' at line 1

Comment: What is the actual error message..   How big is the meta_value field?

Comment: Updated with message. Field is long text.

Comment: Try replacing your single quote deliimters (') with a backtick (`), see if this helps

Comment: That doesn't work.

Comment: It's looks as PHPMyAdmin bug. It try to split query string by semicolon sign `;` and run as multiple queries. I'm not similar with PHPMyAdmin but can abvice to use another MySQL GUI such as MySQLYog or HeidiSQL

Comment: My apologies for confusion, I only meant to put the backticks around the value you are trying to to set. I.E.   `a:1:{i:0....

Comment: @Sparky That's clearly wrong. Backticks are not for strings, they're for database/table/column names.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the error at db-fiddle.com. I suspect @SlavaRozhnev is right that it's a PhpMyAdmin bug.

Comment: That error message would come from MySQL itself, not phpMyAdmin. A phpMyAdmin warning would be shown with a red X to the left of the query window and say something like "Unexpected beginning of statement" or "Unrecognized keyword". Which phpMyAdmin and MySQL versions are you using?

Comment: Have you tried changing your `'a:1:...'` string to different, simpler values (e.g. 'z') to see what happens? Is it possible the string contains characters that aren't what they appear to be?